# sh: .ssh/authorized_keys: Is a directory?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to copy a /id_rsa.pub to another machine with the command

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@10.0.2.15 'cat >>
.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

but keep getting the error

```
sh: .ssh/authorized_keys: Is a directory
```

I created the directory with the following commands

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The output from the command on the target machine

```
ls -l /root/.ssh
```

is "total 0"

Comment: Can you ssh to the remote machine as root, using password?

Comment: yes, i can ssh with password

Comment: If you're logged in as root on your local machine, does `ssh-copy-id root@10.0.2.15` give the same error?

Comment: I've just noticed that your first command is missing the `~/` before `.ssh/authorized_keys`, is that the same as the command that you used?

Comment: Is there a directory named `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you've made a directory called `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This is supposed to be a file. I'm not sure how this has happened, given that the commands you've listed should have just made the `~/.ssh` directory and an `authorized_keys` file within it.

Remove the authorized keys directory on the remote machine, and replace with a file. Or even better, use the `ssh-copy-id` command from the local machine to create the file and add the key in one single command:

```
ssh-copy-id user@ip-address
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i have also tried the ssh-copy-id command and got the same error.

Comment: Have you deleted the authorized_keys file?

Comment: yes, ive tried a few different attempts over the past hour.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -l /root/.ssh` on the remote machine.

Comment: recreating everything and running that command again gives me the following

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 Nov 1 12:13 authorized_keys

Comment: Have you used the `ssh-copy-id` command, or the `cat` command? (Making sure that you include `~/` in front of the `.ssh` part)